# Natbib: "Undefined Control Sequence" error when citing multiple authors

Tags: natbib

I'm a beginner with Latex and I'm using TexStudio with `natbib` and one of the style files mentioned here: https://pubsonline.informs.org/authorportal/latex-style-files

When I try to cite an entry with more than 1 author like this: `\citep[p.38f]{Hassija.2020}`, I get an "Undefined Control Sequence" error. The corresponding .bib entry looks like this:

```
@article{Hassija.2020,
 abstract = {IET Quantum Communication 2020.1:35-41},
 author = {Hassija, Vikas and Chamola, Vinay and Goyal, Adit and Kanhere, Salil S. and Guizani, Nadra},
 year = 2020,
 title = {Forthcoming applications of quantum computing: peeking into the future},
 pages = {35--41},
 volume = {1},
 number = {2},
 issn = {2632-8925},
 journal = {IET Quantum Communication},
 doi = {10.1049/iet-qtc.2020.0026},
 file = {Forthcoming applications of quantum:C\:\\Users\\doc.pdf}
}
```

For entries with exactly one author, everything seems to work fine. Would be very thankful for help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You mention "one of the style files" -- which one, in particular?

Comment: The problem might be the backslashes in the `file` field (that could be mistaken for control sequences by LaTeX). Try to remove that entire field and see if the error persists.

Comment: I used this one: Management Science Style Files

Comment: @Marijn this didn't work unfortunately. I want to highlight that I have other references of the same format in my .bib file that work just fine, the only difference is that in the working ones I have exactly one author and in the non working ones I have more than one author.

Comment: Could you try to find the full error message? LaTeX doesn't just say _Undefined Control Sequence_, it also tells you the name of the control sequence that is not defined. In TexStudio it may be difficult to find the actual full text of the error, but somewhere in the Log tab or the Log File tab there should be more information.

Comment: @Marijn yeah the full error msg says:
! Undefined control sequence.
\b@Hassija.2020 ...amola, Goyal, Kanhere, \BIBand 
                                                  {} Guizani}}
l.6 ...dwide emissions \citep[p.38f]{Hassija.2020}
                                                  . %TODO <src: Statista Rep...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.